# CodeIgniter: Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object

Tags: database, codeigniter, object, autoload

I am getting the above error while I'm trying to trying to access a function from my library as shown...

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_crud {

public function select_from($select, $from) {
    // dafaults
    $output = "";
    // querying
    $this->db->select($select);
    $this->db->from($from);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    // if no rows returned
    if ($uqery->num_rows == 0) {
        return $output = "No Results Found";
    }
    // if row(s) retunred
    return $output = $query->result_array();
}
}
```

while the `database` library is set as autoload.

Comment: After extending the class I'm getting this error ``Fatal error: Class 'CI_model' not found ``

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) and check your capitalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are creating it in a library you should get an instance of CI you could add it on your `__construct`

```
class My_crud
{
 var $ci;
 public function __construct()
 {
  $this->ci =& get_instance();
 }
}
```

then on your method within the class change `this->db` to `$this->ci->db`, the question is why are you making a crud on a library when you can make it inside a model?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to utilize CodeIgniter super object resources, you need to use the `get_instance()` function, as documented under [Utilizing CodeIgniter Resources within your Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html).

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->db->select($select) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to extend something. The way it is setup right now `$this->db` is looking for a `$db` parameter within the `My_crud` class which does not exist.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_crud extends CI_Model {

    public function select_from($select, $from) {
        // defaults
        $output = "No Results Found";

        // querying
        $query = $this->db
            ->select($select)
            ->get($from);

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            $output = $query->result_array();

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now I am getting this ``Fatal error: Class 'CI_model' not found ``

Comment: He specified library, not model. Libraries don't extend models.

Comment: If he is making a CRUD model I would suggest extending the CI_Model and not making a library.